# main application catching event from a dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio

Here is what I want to do with C# and WPF, but have limited idea how to design and implement:

- The system consists of **an dll/assembly (monitor.dll)** and **a main application (main.exe)**.
- monitor.dll is watching a txt file that gets update when some other macro is running. When the txt file is done updating/finish being written, the monitor.dll should release a signal that can be detected by the main.exe.
- The whole process does not have to be frequent. The monitor.dll can check the txt file every quarter second, and the frequency that the main.exe check if the monitor.dll has sent a "done" signal can be on the same order.

I am wondering how should I design the system? What technique should I use? Should I use BackGroundWorker int the assembly?

Right now I am using a timer tick in both the monotor.dll and main.exe, but it seems although the monitor.dll can catch the event, but the main.exe will always not be able to catch the signal sent by the assembly. Thanks.

Comment: Create a public class in the DLL that provides an event (that is raised whenever the file is changed). Instantiate this class in the main application and subscribe to this event. Consider using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to watch a specific file or folder.

Comment: Do you have to use that DLL ? Maybe your main application could do it by itself using this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Yes I have to use that dll, otherwise I image it would have been much easier.

Comment: @NicoSchertler How do I raise event in the dll, and how do I detect the event in the main application? Some sample code?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I mean, I think I can catch the event in dll because if I put a break point inside the dll, it will be hit when the txt file done writting. However, if I don't put a break point inside the dll, not thing happens to the main application.

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx). In order to create an event, you need to define a delegate for the signature, declare the event in the class and then call it like a normal method (after checking for `null`). In the main application you subscribe to the event by `dllInstance.EventName += methodName;`.

Comment: Why are you making a big deal about handling an event raised from a type defined in a DLL?  Is the Button class not defined in the System.Windows.Forms.dll assembly?  Can you not handle the Click event of a Button easily?  As for raising an event, check this out: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the assembly, I used a timer to periodically check the .txt file status, something like this:

System.Timers.Timer _logFileCheckTimer;

```
    public FijiLauncherControl()

    {        // timer set up
                    _logFileCheckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(250);  
                    _logFileCheckTimer.Enabled = true;
                    _logFileCheckTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_logFileCheckTimer_Elapsed);
                   _logFileCheckTimer.Start();  // start the timer

     }    

     void _logFileCheckTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_processOn && IsLogOn)
            {
                try
                {
                    _processFinished = CheckStatuts();  // checking file status

                    if (_processFinished) // fire event if checking status returns true
                    {
                        OnIjmFinished(EventArgs.Empty);
                        _processOn = false;
                        _logFileCheckTimer.Stop();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

In the aseembly. setup a event in the dll that will be triggered if the `_processFinished = CheckStatuts();` returns `true`:

// event delegate
    public delegate void IjmFinishedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
     public event IjmFinishedEventHandler IjmFinished;  // event handler

```
   protected virtual void OnIjmFinished(EventArgs e)
   {
      if (IjmFinished != null)   // trigger event
                IjmFinished(this, e);          
   }
```

In the main application, there should be event receiver, something like this:

```
private FijiLauncherControl _fl; // the object of your assembly

  _fl.IjmFinished += new IjmFinishedEventHandler(_fl_IjmFinished); // event from the assembly should trigger an event handler

   void _fl_IjmFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)   // event handler
        {
            _vm.IjmFinished = true;   // a boolean var in viewmodel in main app set to be true once the event from the assembly is triggered

            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

That should do the job.

Comment: I tried to edit this, but this is really hard to edit. I cannot make it look like code by using the code button on the menu bar.